# Excluding Path While Compressing with TAR/GZ

Tags: linux, unix, gzip, tar, compression

I am compressing list of files like this:

```
tar cvzf  mycompress.tar.gz /dir1/dir2/file1.txt /dir1/dir2/file2.txt
```

However when I uncompressed them the directory `/dir1/dir2/` is still preserved.
How to exclude that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
tar cz -C /dir1/dir2 -f mycompress.tar.gz file1.txt file2.txt
```

That will leave out the path information in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encrypt only files and not directory (is this that you want to do? I'm not sure), then try to use find to exclude directories:

```
tar cvzf  mycompress.tar.gz ` find  your_path_starting_point -type f `
```

(Having files with the same name into different directories could be a problem)